# Direct, brute force computation of electric field of homogenous sphere of charge

Tags: electrostatics, integration

I'd like to find the electric field produced by a homogeneous sphere of charge density $\rho$. I know you can use Gauss's law to solve this problem in two seconds. And I know you can simplify the calculation by looking only at points along the $z$-axis, and using the symmetry of the situation to generalize the resulting answer. And of course  you can deal with the potential by regarding the integrand as the gradient of a function and proceeding that way. All of that is fine, but I haven't been able to find a direct approach. And given how bloody complicated the integral seems to be, I personally think it would be really cool to see all the dust settle on the simple final answer:

\begin{align*}
\vec E(r)=\begin{cases}
\dfrac{\rho R^3}{3\epsilon_0}\dfrac{1}{r^2}\hat r & r> R\\
\dfrac{\rho r}{3\epsilon_0}\hat r & r< R.
\end{cases}
\end{align*}

But I'm not able to perform the integrations. I can set it up as

\begin{equation}
\vec E(\vec r) = \frac{\rho}{4\pi\epsilon}\int\frac{\left(\vec r-\vec r'\right)dV'}{\left|\vec r-\vec r'\right|^3}
\end{equation}
And then because
\begin{align*}
\hat r =& \cos\theta\hat z +\sin\theta\cos\phi\hat x  +\sin\theta\sin\phi\hat y \\
\hat r'=& \cos\theta'\hat z+\sin\theta'\cos\phi'\hat x+\sin\theta'\sin\phi'\hat y,
\end{align*}
we have
\begin{equation}
\vec E(\vec r)
= \frac{\rho}{4\pi\epsilon_0}\int
\frac{\left(\vec r-r'\cos\theta'\hat z-r'\sin\theta'\cos\phi'\hat x-r'\sin\theta'\sin\phi'\hat y\right)r'^2\sin\theta'dr'd\theta'd\phi'}{(r^2+r'^2-2rr'(\cos\theta\cos\theta'+\sin\theta\sin\theta'\cos(\phi-\phi')))^{3/2}}.
\end{equation}
But I think the $\phi'$ and $\theta'$ integrals will lead to Elliptic Integrals, or some other special functions I don't have experience with. Can anyone here push it through?

Edit1: secavara has offered a solution that uses a spherical harmonics expansion. I wasn't aware of that expansion, it's quite cool actually. However I'm looking for a direct evaluation of the vector integral as presented, rather than such a clever, clean solution. I suspect it will be interesting...

Edit2: Frobenius' and G. Smith's answers suggest that I should clarify: how can the angular integrals be done without aligning $\vec r$ with the $z$-axis, i.e. setting $\theta=0$? I'm guessing there would be Elliptic integrals that appear in the intermediate steps, but that vanish in the final answer. That vanishing would be really fascinating to see.

Comment: If that still counts as brute force, I would use $\vec{r}$ as the z-axis and use spherical coordinates relative to $\vec{r}$, that makes a lot of the angles go away. Then integrate over the azimuth $\phi$. And then try to integrate the rest, I guess the $\theta$-stuff (didn't finish it; am a bit rusty, but looks doable).

Comment: That's right, a sane person would do something like that. Griffith's and HRK do this, if memory serves... It wouldn't qualify as brute force as I meant it. I think this brute force approach is useless here but it could be interesting to see if the basic approach could be applied to slightly more complicated $\rho(\vec r)$ which can't be solved with Gauss's law.

Answer (score 3):

A possible sensible approach to the direct integration involves the very useful expansion
\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{|\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{x'}|} = 4 \pi \sum_{l=0}^\infty \sum_{m=-l}^l \frac{1}{2l+1} \frac{r^l_<}{r_>^{l+1}} Y^*_{lm}(\theta',\phi') Y_{lm}(\theta,\phi) \, ,
\end{equation}
where $r_<$ is the smaller of $|\mathbf{x}|$ and $|\mathbf{x'}|$, and $r_>$ the larger of the two. You can find it as equation $(3.70)$ in Jackson's Classical Electrodynamics. In particular, the integral for the potential $\Phi(\mathbf{x})$ becomes much simpler
\begin{eqnarray}
\Phi(\mathbf{x}) &=& \frac{1}{4 \pi \epsilon_0} \int \frac{\rho(\mathbf{x'})}{|\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{x'}|} d^3 x'
\\
&=& \frac{3 Q}{4 \pi R^3 \epsilon_0} \sum_{l=0}^\infty \sum_{m=-l}^l \frac{1}{2l+1} Y_{lm}(\theta,\phi) \int_0^R \frac{r^l_<}{r_>^{l+1}} r'^2 dr' \int d \Omega' \, Y^*_{lm}(\theta',\phi')
\\
&=& \frac{3 Q}{4 \pi R^3 \epsilon_0} \int_0^R \frac{1}{r_>} r'^2 dr'
\\ 
&=&
\begin{array}{cc}
   & 
    \begin{array}{cc}
      \frac{Q}{8 \pi R^3 \epsilon_0} (3R^2-r^2) & \mathrm{, \, if} \, \, r \leq R \\
      \frac{Q}{4 \pi \epsilon_0 r} & \mathrm{, \, if} \, \, R < r
    \end{array}
\end{array}
\, .
\end{eqnarray}
Finally, $\mathbf{E}(\mathbf{x}) = - \nabla \Phi(\mathbf{x})$ matches the expected result.

Comment: That's a very neat factorization, I wasn't aware of it. This is yet another example of why potentials are easier to work with than fields. But, the integral for the potential can also be performed straightforwardly without using this nice expansion. I will reemphasize in the post that, while this is the sensible approach to take practically, it would be great to see how the electric field integral could be solved directly, without recourse to the potential.

Comment: I'm not sure if cubing the expansion will still be useful, the resulting integrals would involve powers of the spherical harmonics, and a quick wikipedia search didn't reveal any nice integration identities.

Comment: You don't have to cube the expansion to use it in the integral for the field. Use the fact that $\nabla \frac{1}{|\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{x'}|} = - \frac{\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{x'}}{|\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{x'}|^3}$, which is precisely what you need, but take the gradient of the expansion instead.

Comment: Oh, I see what you meant by your last comment. I misread it at first, sorry... Though I really am hoping for a solution that manages to confront the integral more "head-on". That would be cool...

Answer (score 1):

The reason that the integral looks complicated is that you haven't made use of your freedom to choose a convenient coordinate system to simplify it.

If you choose to make the polar $z$-axis of a spherical coordinate system pass through the point $\vec r$ where you want to calculate the field, then you have

$$\vec r = r \hat z$$

and

$$\vec r' = r'\sin\theta'\cos\phi'\hat x + r'\sin\theta'\sin\phi'\hat y + r'\cos\theta'\hat z$$

so

$$\vec r - \vec r' = -r'\sin\theta'\cos\phi'\hat x - r'\sin\theta'\sin\phi'\hat y + (r - r'\cos\theta')\hat z$$

and

$$|\vec r -\vec r'|^2 = r^2+r'^2-2rr'\cos\theta'.$$

The field is

$$\vec E=\frac{\rho}{4\pi\epsilon_0}\int_{r<R}r'^2 dr' \sin\theta' d\theta' d\phi'\frac{-r'\sin\theta'\cos\phi'\hat x - r'\sin\theta'\sin\phi'\hat y + (r - r'\cos\theta')\hat z}{(r^2+r'^2-2rr'\cos\theta')^{3/2}}.$$

The integration over $\phi'$ is trivial. The $x$ and $y$ components of the field vanish because integrating $\cos\phi'$ and $\sin\phi'$ from $0$ to $2\pi$ gives zero. You're left with the $z$ component, which has no dependence on $\phi'$ so the $\phi'$ integral produces a factor of $2\pi$, giving

$$\vec E=\hat z\frac{\rho}{2\epsilon_0}\int_{r<R}r'^2 dr' \sin\theta' d\theta' \frac{r - r'\cos\theta'}{(r^2+r'^2-2rr'\cos\theta')^{3/2}}.$$

To integrate over $\theta'$, change the variable of integration to $u=\cos\theta'$, getting

$$\vec E=\hat z\frac{\rho}{2\epsilon_0}\int_0^R r'^2 dr' \int_{-1}^1  \frac{(r - r'u)du}{(r^2+r'^2-2rr'u)^{3/2}}.$$

The first indefinite $u$ integral is elementary

$$\int\frac{du}{(a-bu)^{3/2}}=\frac{2}{b(a-bu)^{1/2}}$$

and the second not much harder:

$$\int\frac{u\,du}{(a-bu)^{3/2}}=\frac{4a-2bu}{b^2(a-bu)^{1/2}}.$$

I will let you work out that the result is that

$$\int_{-1}^1  \frac{(r - r'u)du}{(r^2+r'^2-2rr'u)^{3/2}}=\begin{align*}
\begin{cases}
\frac{2}{r^2} & r'<r \\
0 & r'>r.
\end{cases}
\end{align*}$$

Thus

$$\vec E=\frac{\rho\hat z}{\epsilon_0 r^2}\int_0^R r'^2 dr'\begin{align*}
\begin{cases}
1 & r'<r \\
0 & r'>r.
\end{cases}
\end{align*}$$

To simplify this further, consider the two cases that $r<R$ or $r>R$.

When $r<R$, we have

$$\vec E=\frac{\rho\hat z}{\epsilon_0 r^2}\int_0^r r'^2 dr'=\frac{\rho r}{3\epsilon_0}\hat r.$$

When $r>R$, we have

$$\vec E=\frac{\rho\hat z}{\epsilon_0 r^2}\int_0^R r'^2 dr'=\frac{\rho R^3}{3\epsilon_0 r^2}\hat r.$$

In the final expression, I've written $\hat r$ instead of $\hat z$, because the choice of the $z$-axis through $\vec r$ was just a convenience.

Comment: G. Smith, what you've described is the approach any reasonable person should take for obtaining the answer efficiently. But I'm asking the different question of how an unreasonable person could perform the integrals without using the freedom that you exploited, and yet still obtain the simple answer that you did. See my second Edit in the OP.

Comment: Your second edit appeared as I was writing my answer. However, if I had read your original question more carefully, I would have understood what you were asking and not wasted my time. The fault is entirely mine.

Comment: I appreciate your efforts to help me. Hopefully you got something interesting out of it as well.

Answer (score 0):

There is another way to reach your results by simple integrals.

**Step 1 :**  Consider a spherical surface of radius $\:\alpha\:$ with homogeneous surface charge density $\:\sigma$. By simple integrals you could find for the electric field intensity
\begin{align}
\mathbf{E}\left(\mathbf{r}\right) & \boldsymbol{=} 
\begin{cases}
\hphantom{\dfrac{1}{4\pi\epsilon_0}\tfrac{1}{4}}\boldsymbol{0} & \text{for}\quad r\boldsymbol{=}\Vert\mathbf{r}\Vert\boldsymbol{<} \alpha\\ 
\dfrac{1}{4\pi\epsilon_0}\left(\dfrac{4\pi\sigma\alpha^2}{r^3}\right)\mathbf{r} & \text{for}\quad r\boldsymbol{=}\Vert\mathbf{r}\Vert\boldsymbol{\ge} \alpha
\end{cases}  
\tag{01}\label{01}\\
\text{or}&
\nonumber\\
\mathbf{E}\left(\mathbf{r}\right)&\boldsymbol{=} 
\begin{cases}
\hphantom{\dfrac{1}{4\pi\epsilon_0}}\boldsymbol{0} & \text{for}\quad r\boldsymbol{=}\Vert\mathbf{r}\Vert\boldsymbol{<} \alpha\\ 
\dfrac{1}{4\pi\epsilon_0}\dfrac{q_\sigma(\alpha)}{r^3}\mathbf{r} & \text{for}\quad r\boldsymbol{=}\Vert\mathbf{r}\Vert\boldsymbol{\ge} \alpha
\end{cases}  
\tag{02}\label{02} 
\end{align}
where
\begin{equation}
q_\sigma(\alpha)\boldsymbol{=}4\pi\sigma\alpha^2 \boldsymbol{=}\texttt{total charge of spherical surface}  
\tag{03}\label{03} 
\end{equation}
The empty ball (interior of the spherical surface) is an equipotential region while in the exterior the electric field is that produced by a point charge $q_\sigma(\alpha)$ on the center.

**Step 2 :** Consider now a ball of radius $\:R\:$ with homogeneous volume charge density $\:\rho$. Linearity and the result in **Step 1**, equation \eqref{02}, relieve us from the brutality of heavy integration. Precisely, we do not need any integration.

At first imagine that all the ball of radius $\:R\:$ is like an onion consisted of shells of radius $\:\alpha\:$ and infinitesimal thickness $\:\rm d\alpha\:$ where $\:\alpha\:$ runs from $\:0\:$ to $\:R$. Each shell is considered as a spherical surface of radius $\:\alpha\:$ with surface charge density $\:\sigma(\alpha)\boldsymbol{=}\rho\,\rm d\alpha$ (this is informative, we do not need it anywhere).

A point in the ball, that is $\:r\boldsymbol{<}R\:$, is interior for the group of shells with $\:\alpha\in (r,R)\:$ and exterior for the group of shells with $\:\alpha\in (0,r)$. So, according to equation \eqref{02} the first group doesn't participate to the electric field while the second group produces the electric field as if all its charge is concentrated on the center
\begin{equation}
\mathbf{E}\left(\mathbf{r}\right) \boldsymbol{=} \dfrac{1}{4\pi\epsilon_0}\dfrac{\left(\dfrac{4\pi\rho r^3}{3}\right)}{r^3}\mathbf{r}\boldsymbol{=}\dfrac{\rho}{3\,\epsilon_0}\,\mathbf{r}
\tag{04}\label{04} 
\end{equation}

For a point in the exterior of the ball , that is $\:r\boldsymbol{\ge}R$
\begin{equation}
\mathbf{E}\left(\mathbf{r}\right) \boldsymbol{=} \dfrac{1}{4\pi\epsilon_0}\dfrac{\left(\dfrac{4\pi\rho R^3}{3}\right)}{r^3}\,\mathbf{r}\boldsymbol{=}\dfrac{\rho R^3}{3\,\epsilon_0 }\dfrac{1}{r^3}\,\mathbf{r}
\tag{05}\label{05} 
\end{equation}
So finally
\begin{equation}
\boxed{\:\:
\mathbf{E}\left(\mathbf{r}\right)\boldsymbol{=} 
\begin{cases}
\:\:\:\:\dfrac{\rho}{3\,\epsilon_0}\,\mathbf{r} & \text{for}\quad r\boldsymbol{=}\Vert\mathbf{r}\Vert\boldsymbol{<} R \vphantom{\dfrac{a}{\dfrac{a}{b}}}\\
\:\:\dfrac{\rho R^3}{3\,\epsilon_0 }\dfrac{1}{r^3}\,\mathbf{r} & \text{for}\quad r\boldsymbol{=}\Vert\mathbf{r}\Vert\boldsymbol{\ge} R
\end{cases}\:\:}
\tag{06}\label{06} 
\end{equation}

Comment: But this essentially describes performing the angular integrals first and then the radial integral, in the triple integral of my original post. Can you evaluate your integrals to get your electric field in Step 1 \emph{without} making simplifying assumptions that align $\vec r$ and with the $z$-axis? Making that assumption, i.e. setting $\theta$ in my original post to zero, yields an integral that is very much doable. But I'm curious about the much harder integral... I think it would be really cool to get the simple answer from the apparently complicated integral.